# How to Log all Incoming Request in Spring REST Services

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logging, spring-data

Hi I am using Spring framework to build REST full web services . I want to log all the incoming request to my service. Is there any way I can log all the incoming request to my web service.

Comment: What about a servlet filter that logs to log4j?

Comment: In which application server are you running your services?

Comment: I am running my services in Apache Tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

You could use Filter or Interceptor if you need very basic solution. Just inject your service into it, and override "preHandle(HttpServletRequest request..."

Problems will come when you decide that you need to:

- log only some requests (E.g. only PUT and POST)
- exclude some data (e.g. passwords, keys, etc)
- exclude files
- parse data to extract information to persist it
- know if it return success or failure or exception

Then better solution would be to call that service directly from controllers.